# Using a native struct from C# without redefining it

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a native application that I'm writing a WPF GUI for where the two separate processes communicate via a pipe. I want to define a single set of structs that will be passed across the pipe and used by both the native and managed applications. At it's most basic level it looks like this:

```cpp
// gui_protocol.h (C++ App)
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
}
```

```cpp
// gui_interop.cpp (C++/CLI Middle Layer)
#include "gui_protocol.h"
#pragma make_public(Foo)
```

```cs
// gui.cs (C# WPF GUI)
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = 2; // This doesn't work!
```

The trouble is that last line. The fields of Foo are not visible to the C# application. It appears marking the struct public only creates information about the name and size and not the members. This is what the metadata shows:

[image]

These structs are intended to be plain old data and I don't anticipate the need for marshaling. I know that I can write an equivalent struct in managed code using `StructLayout` and such, but I'd like to avoid having duplicate definitions that can end up with mismatches.

**Question:** Is there any way to utilize these native structs without needing to redefine them on the managed side?

Comment: Marshaling is required, the C++/CLI compiler is not allowed to make assumptions about managed layout since it is a CLR implementation detail.  It makes extra sure you can't shoot your leg off by omitting the members.  Fwiw, [NativeCppClass] is a decent hint, there is no runtime distinction between a class and a struct in native C++.  You *must* redeclare the struct, you can do so with `public value struct`.  This can be automated so the odds for a typo or versioning trouble are low with SWIG, but that generally isn't worth the trouble unless you have a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks, that's about what I expected. Currently just pushing the pipe reading and translation onto the C++ /CLI side so the WPF side doesn't need deal with any native data.